# C# add reference to sqlite.dll in class library project from another project

Tags: c#, sqlite, portable-class-library

Here are the steps I used to build these two Projects ADBTest and DBControl.
ADBTest was built first it implements `SQLite DB CRUD` functions I added System.Data.SQLite with NuGet.
Ran the project everything functions great!
Next I built the DBControl it is a Windows Forms Class Library.I added this to the ADBTest project.
Added Existing Project and Added Reference to DBControl to ADBTest.
Now I tried to add Reference to the SQLite.dll in ADBTest the DBContro.csproj says it there I think
Here is were I start getting LOST. Will Post some code and a screen shot.
I did various using declaration but that does not work nothing is found to USE.
**So where did I make the mistake or is the code design all off?**
Also not sure how to call this code from frmStart? Work on that later one question RULE sucks!
DBControl has NO form so when it is done with makeFriendsTable will try to send it back to frmStart round trip flight I hope.

```
public class DBControl : UserControl
{
    public static string dbName = "APeople.db";
    // Class1

    private void UserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        makeDB();
        makeFriendsTable();
    }

    private void makeDB()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void makeFriendsTable()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public class MakeDB
    {
        public void makeDB()
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
                if (!File.Exists(dbName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
        }
```

Here is the frmStart Call

```
        private void btnCreateDB_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        using (var form = new DBControl.DBControl())
        Show();

        //DBControl dB = new DBControl();
        //dB.Show();
    }
```

The Weird Part after putting the SQLite in after the two projects were joined in Visual Studio 
First NuGet insisted they be installed in BOTH Projects
Then the DB and Table were created but I could not find the DB in the Solution Explorer
Went looking in the source folder on C Drive it was in DBCall Debug folder

Comment: I don't understand (sorry if I'm a little confuse here) why are you trying to reference a third party reference. Why don't every project has a reference by itself, or why do you need a reference to SQlite from the other project. Or what are the relations between the projects? It can be maybe a wrong design of the architecture layers?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I tried to add the SQLite to the DBControl but because it is a Class Library with no form that makes adding impossible. Perhaps I should add a Form and add SQLite to just the DBControl and only make calls from the ADBTest Project Still learning how to deal with Class Library & Control Library Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that can be a design problem. Is not so simple as seems to be, and even working with a correct design can bring some problems, so the question for me is useful.

The common work is made layers of work, one with the interface, one with the logic, one with the data handle.... that's the three layers model. There are several designs to work, but this is the common one.

The layer that handles the data is often called `Data Layer` (DAL) and in microservices or SQL servers is often called `Data Service` (DAS)

The topic indeed is very large to explain but you can get a reference with the following image. Of course you can see this model in a lot of different ways but you will find the same principle:

[image]

As I understand from your case, you have a `DBControl` that handle the data work. So this is the one who carried the reference to the database and SQLite.dll. By the way you can use Entity Framework to work with SQLite and make an scaffolding to the archive.

In any case, this DBControl will carry the "repositories" with the methods where you make the calls to the database, being ADO or EF. This is the `Persistance` and can handle also the `Domain Model`

Those methods will return not the EF or DB models, instead your own models that will help and work in your "business logic". Those are the classes, objects, models, etc that the DBControl will `export` for other libraries or the interface layer where the apps will work.

***Since the `DBControl` will returns your own models, the interface won't need the SQLite reference, but the `DBControl` reference in order to get the models you work there***

The image is a design to follow, but is not a rule. You can have all the layers in the same project and every layer is a .cs file, or in the same file and every layer is a method, the trick is the organization. And maybe you don't have all the layers, it depends on your design.

If you require more detail in this answer please comment, I'll glad to help you

Comment: I am complemented by your statement so the question for me is useful I have used the DAL in another project but the manipulation of all the static string too much code. I am not use to Entity Framework so need to look at that. I will try this design place a Form in DBControl and attach SQLite to that form then create a new C# Net project that ONLY calls the methods in the DBControl The issue will be getting data back to the calling form More static string Let me try that then I might ask for more detail Is your profile pic 11 years old ? That would mean your helper is coding

Comment: Thanks a lot Vector for your words. No, my pic is from 2022 is my daughter! Im still learning. I have some experiencie in sqlite with EF and Im sure you can handle it, is more easy now than 3 or 4 years before. If you make another question please comment here so Im notice it!

Comment: I added an Edit to the Question I am able to Create the DB and Add Data Still have to play with static strings to manipulate the CRUD functions I could not create the DB when I added SQLite to DBControl with a Form Here is the ERROR I got   Message=Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found So I deleted SQLite when they were joined and re added SQLite that is when the fun started I Think NOT sure I will post an Answer Will put code on GitHub when I am done if you are interested at a look see Keep Learning

Comment: Hey posted some of my solution and I now have a working Class Library that does the CRUD work on a SQLite DB it also creates the DB and Tables in the Class Library and I can pass in the DB id from the main project to do the Read Update & Delete If you want the full code let me know I will put it on GitHub Keep an eye on the little one she looks like a hand full ha ha

Comment: Nice one @Vector! You could make a new question and answer itself with the code like a "how to make a crud with sqlite", I think it will be get more upvotes (mine to begin) because this question is more specific to another thing.

Comment: Brdelli Might do that but I have never been much for the upvote system. I do appreciate and try to say Thank You for responses and for answers that help. Saying Thank You was frowned on here sometime back As of Now I have used Inno Setup but no idea how to deal with two projects that are attached ? ? ? Question Time my best

Comment: youre welcome! I didn't understand very well your last problem with inno setup but if you make a question please add the link here and I will check it if I know the answer

Answer (score 1):

First I had to create the First C# .net framework project
Then I created the Class Library project that would handle the CRUD work for the SQLite DB.
Then I attached the Class Library to the First Project
Then I used NuGet to add the System Data SQLite to BOTH projects.
This seemed counter intuitive but it works.
OK how to pass an integer ID into the Class Library most of the code I found on SO people we passing variables OUT of the CL NOT into it.
Here is the little method I used to pass in udID and assign it to a local variable newData which I can use to make SQL calls to the DB in the Class Library

```
    public void UTBW(int udID)
    {
        newData = udID;
        return;
    }
```

Here is the code in the CL that uses newData

```
        public void readUDV()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM FriendsData WHERE FID = " + newData , conn))
            {
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {  
                        fn = rdr["fxFirstName"].ToString().Trim();
                        ln = rdr["fxLastName"].ToString().Trim();
                        rt = rdr["fxInfo"].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

One other issue I faced was how to populate a Data Grid View that was not in the Class Library enter stage left the trusty Generic List.Here is the code that populates the list it is in the Class Library.

```
  public List<object> readData(List<object> list)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM FriendsData", conn))
            {
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        gv_parentInt = rdr["FID"].ToString().Trim();
                        list.Add(gv_parentInt);
                        gv_firstName = rdr["fxFirstName"].ToString().Trim();
                        list.Add(gv_firstName);
                        gv_lastName = rdr["fxLastName"].ToString().Trim();
                        list.Add(gv_lastName);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return list;
    }
```

Great it returns the list to the form in the First project that needs to populate the DataGridView with the list data.

```
    public void loadDGV()
    {
        frmHDB form = new frmHDB();
        {
            form.readData(list);
            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                dgvPerson.Rows.Add(list[i], list[i + 1], list[i + 2]);
                i = i + 3;
                dgvPerson.Sort(dgvPerson.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            }  
        }
    }
```

I am not too sure about my counter i = i + 3 IT works
Don't Forget you need to add the Class Library dll to the First Project.
As for portability and Class Library's NOT SO MUCH
I tried to attache this CL to another and project and I changed the name of the database in the CL. Went back to my original two projects and WHAT it quit working YEP the name of the database gets set to the new project DB name. Two hours later I discovered the cause of the ERROR.
Just create a new Class Library they are NOT portable as advertised.